# Reversing a number in c++

Tags: c++

I created a program to show the sum and show the reversed number a person has typed. The sum function works but the revers function is not. Can anyone give me any tips on how to fix it.
I created a program to show the sum and show the reversed number a person has typed. The sum function works but the revers function is not. Can anyone give me any tips on how to fix it.

```
  #include<iostream>
    #include<iomanip> 

    using namespace std;

    void printSum(int n, bool reverse);
    int sm(int n);
    int reverseInt(int n);
    void printAddTable(int n);
    int main()
    {   
    int reverse;
       int sum=0;
           int n;
        cout<<"Enter N value:"<<endl;
        cin>>n;

        if(n>0)
        {
           reverse = true;
           printSum( n, reverse);    // calls the printSum Method
        }
        else
        {
          //cout<<"enter positive Number only:"<<endl;
        }
            sum = sm(n);        //err    // calls the sum Method
         reverse = reverseInt(n);    // calls the reverseInt Method
        cout<<"The reverse value is:"<<reverse;
        printAddTable(n);            // calls the printAddTable Method
        //getch()
       }
       //end of main()
     void printSum(int n, bool reverse)
    {

    int sum=0;            
                        // print sum of reverse numbers
    for(int i=n; i>=1; i--)
    {
    sum=sum+i;
    cout<<i<< " "<<"+"<<" ";

    }
    cout<<sum;
    }

    int sm(int n)
    {int sum =0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
         sum = sum + i ;
    cout << endl;

    cout<<i<<" "<<"+"<<" "<<endl;            // print n positive integers
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout<< "Are " <<n<< " positive integers"<<endl;
    cout<< "Sum is "<<sum <<endl;





    return sum;
    }

    int reverseInt(int n)
    {
    int reminder=0;

     int sum =0;    

    while(n<=0)
    {

    reminder = n/10;
    sum = (sum * 10) + reminder;        // it returns the reverse number
    n = n % 10;
    }
    return sum;

    }
    void printAddTable(int n)
    {
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
    cout<<i<<endl;
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)            // print n X n add table
    {
    cout<<i+j<<endl;    

    }
    }
    }
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, following is to be changed in `reverseInt` function as mentioned by the comment.

```
while(n<0)
{

//reminder = n/10; should be
 reminder = n%10;
sum = (sum * 10) + reminder;        // it returns the reverse number
//n = n % 10;
//Should be
n = n/10; //or n /= 10;
}
```

Comment: The test needs to change from while (n <= 0) to while (n > 0) as well.